# Fields in Word: OR function

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013, field-codes

I'm using fields for a complex mailmerge.
I'd like to use an OR function, but I can't seem to get it to work; `if a=0 or a=""`
I'm assuming I must follow the excel format; `OR(a=0; a="")`
I do find the `OR` function in the formula dialog of word, it does show OR().
But in word I can't get it to work, with spaces between conditions, comma, semicolon but all of them give a syntax error.

I'm trying this in a new blank document (without mailmerge)

```
 {IF OR(2=2 1=2) "matched" "not matched"}
```

it returns literally "'Syntaxisfout, )"
Mind the comma space round bracket! It feels like the Syntax error is more in the "1=2" instead in the OR function

Any idea on how to use the `{=OR()}` function in a field in word?

**Edit**; It rather seems a problem starting in my IF structure and comparing textual values, it works with spaces, but that doesn't allow to nest the OR in the IF.
Things I've tried:

- `{ =IF(OR(2=2;1=2);2;1) }` >>  works
- `{ =IF(OR("a"="a";1=2);2;1) }` >>  Syntax Error
- `{ IF "<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€‎ 0,00" "1" "2"}` >> works
- `{ =IF("<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€‎ 0,00";"1";"2") }` >>  syntax error
- `{ IF("<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€‎ 0,00" "1" "2") }` >> empty result (no error, no '1' no '2'), also empty result when comparing "a"="a" without the mergefield.
- `{ IF OR "<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€‎ 0,00" 1=1 "1" "2" }` >>  returns €0,00
- `{ IF OR("<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€ 0,00";1=1) "1" "2" }` >> at this point I become hopeless; returns € 0,00
- `{ OR "<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€ 0,00" 1=1 }` >>  Error bookmark not defined (shouldn't this say 'true' or 'false'?)
- `OR("<<slfn_discount_financial>>"<>"€ 0,00";1=1) }` >> Empty; no return

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regional settings you need to use `,` or `;` to separate ALL ARGUMENTS OF BOTH `IF` and `OR`.

This works for me with UK settings:
`{ =IF(OR(2=2,1=2),2,1) }`

Comment: Word proposes spaces; semicolon also works; The above formula works; but if I change the comparision it suddenly breaks. I'll keep testing but I'm starting to believe it's just a broken feature.

Comment: please post a formula with work. and also please post the same one with the different condition which doesn't work. Without that it's impossible to understand your problem.

Comment: Edited post, I really don't understand it anymore.